# Как можно найти нужный класс в $str = curl_exec($curl)?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

```
    $base = $page;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

получаю вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно в этом найти например тег с классом?
например в HtmlDomParser::file_get_html я искал так

```
$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html($page, false, null, 1)->find(".leftcol > .area > .listItem");
```

Comment: вы в курсе что вы сначала страницу загружаете курлом, а потом через еще раз в file_get_html ?

Answer (score 0):

`$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $str );`
`$result = $dom->find('....');`

Как то так...